# Muy atascado en un índice de error. Indice fuera de rango

Tags: python, lista

Aquí esta mi una lista que tiene listas dentro de ella:

birthlist = [['1994,1,1,**6**,8096'],
 ['1994,1,2,**7**,7772'],
 ['1994,1,3,**1**,10142'],
 ['1994,1,4,**2**,11248'],

Quiero crear una variable (day_of_week) que almacene los numeros que he puesto en negrita, como veis están en el índice 3 cada uno.

Así que procedo:

```
   for b in birthlist:
       day_of_week = b[3]
       print(day_of_week)
```

Pero me da IndexError: list index out of range

Sin embargo he probado a hacer

```
  for b in birthlist:
       print(b)
```

Y si me da cada lista separada, porque entonces no puede sacar el indice 3 de cada una y asignar cada numero en la variable "day_of_week"?

Llevo buscando horas pero no entiendo porque no funciona. Tampoco se salir de aqui, claro. De este error.

Comment: Creo que el problema es que los datos no son lo que esperas que sean. Las sublistas solo tienen una cadena y no las partes individuales. Lo que quieres hacer lo podrías resolver con: `print([e[0].split(',')[3] for e in birthlist])`

Answer (score 0):

Si miras con detenimiento lo que tienes en la lista:

```
birthlist = [['1994,1,1,6,8096'], ['1994,1,2,7,7772'], ['1994,1,3,1,10142'], ['1994,1,4,2,11248']]
```

verás que es una serie de listas, como por ejemplo esta:

```
['1994,1,1,6,8096']
```

la cual **sólo tiene un elemento**, debido a que todo va entre comillas.

Puedes convertir esta lista a otra que sí tendría lo que esperas mediante la siguiente *list comprehension*:

```
birthlist = [e[0].split(",") for e in birthlist]
print(birthlist)
```

```
[['1994', '1', '1', '6', '8096'],
 ['1994', '1', '2', '7', '7772'],
 ['1994', '1', '3', '1', '10142'],
 ['1994', '1', '4', '2', '11248']]
```

O, si necesitas que los elementos sean enteros en vez de cadenas:

```
birthlist = [[int(num) for num in e[0].split(",")] for e in birthlist]
```

```
[[1994, 1, 1, 6, 8096],
 [1994, 1, 2, 7, 7772],
 [1994, 1, 3, 1, 10142],
 [1994, 1, 4, 2, 11248]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que con esta linea `day_of_week = b[3]` estas intentando intentando acceder al elemento que se encuentra en la posición 3 de la lista, pero lo que tiene `b` es una lista con un solo elemento, por ejemplo el primero es `['1994,1,1,6,8096']`. Por eso te muestra el error de que el indice esta fuera del rango posible.

Si ejecutas `len(['1994,1,1,6,8096'])` podrías confirmar de que solo tiene un elemento, a pesar de que visualmente pareciera que tuviera más, ya que es una cadena de texto que esta condensando toda la información.

Para lograr lo que quieres y asumiendo que no puedes cambiar la información debes primero acceder al único elemento de la lista, que se encuentra en la posición 0, y luego debes separar la cadena de texto utilizando el método `split`.

```
for b in birthlist:
  b_list = b[0].split(',') // separas el texto donde haya comas
  print(b_list[3] // ahora si puedes acceder al elemento en la posición 3 de la lista
```